# Android random activites without repetition

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am developing a quiz game, where I have to get random activities on answering the questions as to avoid the questions in same order. I have fixed this by using `switch`

However, the problem is that I may return to questions which I've already answered, so I now have to code something that avoids the player to go to previous questions by the random generator.

I've done this so far;

```
  Random rand = new Random();
  int number = rand.nextInt(10);
  Intent intent = null;

       switch(number){
       case 0: intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Question001.class);
       break;
       case 1: intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Question002.class);
       break;

       //etc....
       }
       startActivity(intent);
```

This brings randomly activities on button click, however I want to disable previously visited questions meaning, if a person has answered the question from class Question002, he must not be able to (never and never) get this question once more, as this will result in his gaining of extra points from earlier questions. How do I randomly get questions on button click only ONCE, so they won't appear again? I hope my question is understood.

Every question is stored in its own class (Question001, Question002.... Question009)

Comment: Are your really sure that you want a Activity for every Question? I would really try to take another approach because this is getting you in real trouble. Try to make one Activity and update the views, store the questions in a database so you can easily add new Questions

Comment: @A.S. Is right. Use the same `Activity` for all questions, just change the view's contents (e.g. set the text) when you want to switch questions. This will also allow you to store previously asked questions right in the `Activity` and use them for picking a unique question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Sorry that my reply is that late, I have been very busy. A.S., I think that what you suggest is better, but since I am a beginner, it is hard for me to do all that in one activity. So I am looking for, how I can do this? And FD_, thank you for your answer, I appreciate it, though I am a beginner and do not really know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create an ArrayList (or a List simply) and add all your Questions to it. Remember this only holds the questions for shuffling. Do not use it for any other purpose.
2. Then do a shuffle using Collections.shuffle(question).
3. Ask the question on top (question.get(0));
4. After this has been answered remove it from the List. This will ensure it is never shown again.
5. Repeat steps 2 - 5 till your List size is greater than zero.

Let me know if it is unclear.

Comment: So you mean something like String[] question = {question1, question2....} that is the first point. And the second one, I should go by simply typing Collections.shuffle(question); Though I did not understand 3 and 4 (am I even correct with the two first ones??) Sorry for the late answer, as I have been very busy

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) number.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(number);
```

Comment: This won't help I'm afraid. How are you able to make sure not to repeat one?

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer and sorry that I am replying after a long time; this is due to my time as I have been busy. I was thinking the same is FD_ that how I should avoid repeating questions. But it looks very good anyway for inspiration for a beginner like me.